# Spinner in ListView(android)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I apologize for my English. I have a lot of time can not figure out how to make a `spinner` in `ListView`. I do not understand how to add items to the `spinner`, and then inserted into the spinner `ListView`. The following attempts to do something similar, please see me on the right track or not? I do not understand how to add `BaseAdapter` `Spinner`. Below is my bad code.

**UDP**

So I do not understand how to do it, that the code does not even compile(
In `BaseAdapter` class I have a method `private Spinner spinnerDetails`, here it emphasizes eclipse line:`ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerArray);`

**UPD**

In order that the error disappeared had to write instead: `ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerArray);` these are: `ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerArray);`now all outputs, spinners appear, but are empty.

**UDP**
Issue has been resolved! Need in MyBaseAdapter write `spinnerArray.add("1");
        spinnerArray.add("2");
        spinnerArray.add("3");
        spinnerArray.add("4");
        spinnerArray.add("5");` Code needs to be rewritten, since a lot of things wrong and unnecessary. Good luck to all!

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCustomList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**loyout_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvDetail;
    Context context = MainActivity.this;
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

    String[] spinArray = new String[] { //spinner items
            "One", "Two", "Three", "Four",
            "Five", "Six"   
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCustomList);
        getDataInList(); //method whitch one add all in spinner
        lvDetail.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList)); //Base adapter
    }

    private void getDataInList() {
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
            ListData ld = new ListData(); 

            ld.SetSpinnerItem(spinArray[i]); //i add items in spinner like this
            myList.add(ld);

        }
    }
```

**ListData**

```
public class ListData {

     String spinnerItems;

     public String getSpinnerItem() {
         return spinnerItems;
     }

     public void SetSpinnerItem(String items) {
         spinnerItems = items;
     }

}
```

**MyBaseAdapter**

```
  public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context context;

        ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();


        public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList myList) {
            this.myList = myList;
            this.context = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ListData getItem(int position) {
            return myList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
                mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
                convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
            } else {
                mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //spinner i dont know how do it
            mViewHolder.sp = spinnerDetails(convertView, R.id.spinner, myList.get(position).getSpinnerItem());

            return convertView;
        }



        private Spinner spinnerDetails(View v, int resId, String text) {
            Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(resId);

//then a bad place. Eclipse not proud of what is written here. 
            ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        spinnerArray);
            mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            return mySpinner;
        }

        private class MyViewHolder {
            Spinner sp;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific with what's wrong with your code. Is it crashing?

Comment: You say that the code does not compile. What errors do you get?

Comment: @CurlyCorvus eclipse emphasizes the red line: `ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        spinnerArray);` and suggests that the `The constructor ArrayAdapter(MyBaseAdapter, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner view does not show the view that you created in getView because you are returning `convertView` instead of the view you created, `mViewHolder`.

Change `return convertView;` to `return mViewHolder;`

This is a separate answer to the error you got. The error was there when you had something else written in that same line, and you either did not save the file or eclipse did not rebuild.
Save the file and rebuild the project.

On Eclipse, press Project -> Clean... and clean the current project. This will remove compiled resources that can be rebuilt automatically.
To rebuild, press Project -> Build Project. If the Build Project is grayed out, your eclipse is set to auto build and will rebuild automatically after cleaning the project.

This should either fix the error or show other errors in your project (if any exists).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have updated the theme, now spinners displayed but empty.

Comment: @asdascascaedfa I've edited my answer. The part I wrote before is a bit off-topic so it's on the bottom of the answer.